# cherry st1044 not recognized in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: usb, hardware

I cannot get Ubuntu 12.10 to recognize my Cherry ST1044 smart terminal reader.  The terminal shows the PCSC software is installed but "no service" is also displayed in the terminal.

Comment: If you run `service pcscd status` what is the return?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. When I check the status of pcscd (the daemon/service that pcsc_scan is trying to contact) the service isn't running. When I try to start it using `service pcscd start`, it doesn't return an error message, but after checking the status again the service still isn't running.

Comment: Also, have you installed the drivers for the card reader? I think the Cherry ST1044 is included in `libccid`.

Comment: FYI. Checked on http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/section.html and the Cherry ST-XX44 series devices are listed under the "supported" section for `libccid`.

Answer (score -2):

The pcscd service is started on demand by systemd. See "[pcscd auto start using systemd](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.fr/2011/11/pcscd-auto-start-using-systemd.html)"
So it is normal if pcscd is NOT started by `service pcscd start`.

See also "[Level 1 smart card support on GNU/Linux](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.fr/2014/03/level-1-smart-card-support-on-gnulinux.html)" to know how to debug your issue.

Comment: When linking to your blog, please add a disclaimer that you're the author (your post was detected as possible spam and seems to have been flagged as such). Also, it's preferable  to add details here so as to provide a complete answer that doesn't rely on external links, which might die in future and just aren't as convenient as having everything necessary in the post. Your answer has some useful information, but the solution to the problem isn't in it. Please [edit] and add the debugging steps here if possible